# Removing PHP file extension when serving PHP files

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm trying to remove the file extension in the address from all `*.php` files in my site. For instance, if a user visits `mysite.com/about.php` I want the URL to read `mysite.com/about`.

Here's my `app.yaml`:

```
application: mysite
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
# Static files
- url: /images/*
  static_dir: images
- url: /css/*
  static_dir: css
- url: /js/*
  static_dir: js

# Routing
- url: /services(.*)
  script: services.php
- url: /portfolio(.*)
  script: portfolio.php
- url: /project(.*)
  script: project.php
- url: /about(.*)
  script: about.php
- url: /contact(.*)
  script: contact.php
- url: /(.*)
  script: index.php
```

How could I achieve this within GAE?

Comment: why is the question specific to gae?

Comment: Because I imagine to achieve this, I would need to edit the app.yaml file. Unless there is another way I'm missing? And that just happens to be the environment I'm using.

Comment: cool to know. upvoted :)

Comment: I'd drop the (.*) part from the urls to better reflect what you wanted to achieve, but the app.yaml looks fine to me as-is.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is perform that type of routing, you could use this:

```
application: mysite
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
# Static files
- url: /images/*
  static_dir: images
- url: /css/*
  static_dir: css
- url: /js/*
  static_dir: js

# Special case, route requests for the root document
- url: /
  script: /index.php
# If the request ends in [something].php, route to that file directly
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: /\1
# Map all other requests to scripts of the same name
# so that, eg, /thispage (or /thispage/) routes to /thispage.php
- url: /(.*?)/?$
  script: /\1.php
```

NB however that using this method you won't be able to handle 404 errors (although they don't appear to be handled in the app.yaml provided in the question either). Error-handlers in your app.yaml won't work for a 404 because they'll only kick in if they can't match any route you've provided.

So, if you want to handle 404 errors and such, what you should do instead is do the routing from inside a php script, like this:

```
-url: /(.*)
 script: /routes.php
```

and inside routes.php inspect the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable to see what page was requested, and serve the appropriate content accordingly.

edit: thanks to @Avinash Raj for cleaning up the regex [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637884/can-these-two-app-yaml-lines-be-combined-into-one)

Comment: I do have to make a few changes (the ? towards the end was trying to serve me .php.php files). Here's what I came up with:
https://regex101.com/r/aD2hP2/1
https://regex101.com/r/lS9sV9/1

Even still, this doesn't solve my issue unfortunately. This does serve `/about.php` when hitting `/about` but I would like the URL to reflect that as well. Maybe there's some way to redirect? I might have to use a separate `routes.php` like you mentioned. I'll reply back if I find a solution.

Comment: Made edits to the example app.yaml in the answer so you can directly access /*.php files (like /about.php) _or_ access them by "friendly" url (like /about or /about/).

Redirecting and showing a new URL in the browser is something I don't think you can do just in the app.yaml. You'll have to do a redirect inside your php code (I place it in a separate file called "routes.php") 

The kind of redirect I think you're talking about can be done in PHP like this:

`header("Location: $url");`

Comment: Yeah, I'm  trying something like that (http://dumptext.com/DZX3xTVb), but my Dev tools tell me that the request gets cancelled. I'm thinking its because the `.php` file that the routing tries to serve gets sent through the routing again; Some sort of recursion. I'm going to keep trying.

Comment: The routes.php itself shouldn't get routed through app.yaml. But yeah you might see it once you redirected the browser to the new .php address. Try the updated app.yaml I posted in this answer; the `- url: /(.+\.php)$` line checks for for urls ending in ".php" and sends them through directly.

Comment: The URLs work just fine, but I'm still running into the issue with removing the `.php` extensions from the URL automatically.