# How to handle trailing slashing in Google App Engine app.yaml

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I ran into this problem trying to answer this SO question here: [Removing PHP file extension when serving PHP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631916/removing-php-file-extension-when-serving-php-files/31637679#31637679)  about how to route certain requests in app.yaml for Google App Engine.

But I couldn't figure out how to map requests for urls which may or may not have a trailing slash with a single app.yaml regular expression. Right now, I'm handling that case with two lines:

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*)/
  script: /\1.php
- url: /(.*)
  script: /\1.php
```

But that seems redundant. Can these two lines be combined into one?

Things I thought should work, like

```
url: /(.*)(/?)
```

and

```
url: /(.*)(/{0,1})
```

and

```
url: /(.*)(/?$)
```

don't seem to work for requests with the trailing slash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use non-greedy regex.

```
/(.*?)/?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iF1hZ7/1)