# how to add trailing slash at end of urls in app yaml

Tags: regex, app.yaml

however mypp.appspot.com/about gives an error.

i have to include the trailing slash

mypp.appspot.com/about/ Is there any way to fix this?

*For example: https://example.com/folder_name/sub_folderName/*

```
am using this:
- url: /(.*)/?$
static_files: www/\1/index.html
upload: www/(.*)/index.html
```

Comment: With your edit, that text is no longer valid YAML

Comment: my question was , i need to use '/ ' slash at end of urls that should redirect to same link , right now its showing 404

Comment: It is unclear to me if I really understand what you want. I read that you want a python/pyyaml based application that adds a slash to a url in your YAML file. If that is not the case, you should edit your question to make unambigiously clear what you want. You should also correct the broken YAML and maybe remove some non-relevant tags (e.g. if you don't want a program). Do not respond by commenting, just edit your question

Comment: > Used non-greedy regex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637884/how-to-handle-trailing-slashing-in-google-app-engine-app-yaml?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

> working

[References](https://gist.github.com/darktable/873098/beddaa449e41954bfb1e86a85f1d8b699cf76a42)

```
- url: /about/?$
      static_files: www/index.html
      upload: www/(.*)



    - url: /about/(.*?)/?$
      static_files: www/\1/index.html
      upload: www/(.*)/index.html
```